# lzss.decode() in python is not giving correct output

Tags: python, python-2.7, compression, python-3.6, decode

I have a compressed file as per LZSS compression method.
I am using `lzss.decode()` in Python for the compressed data. But I am not getting correct output. My code is given below:

```
import lzss    
input_1 = fp.read()

print("\n compressed: ", binascii.hexlify(input_1).decode("ascii"))

comp_out = lzss.decode(input_1)

print("\n uncompressed: ", binascii.hexlify(comp_out).decode("ascii"))
```

Output from code:

[image: output from code]

Correct uncompressed data
[image: correct uncompressed data]

Could any one please help me on the problem?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `encode_file()/decode_file()` methods of lzss to compress/decompress the whole file. I did not have a problem with them.